# Importing .dll / .tlb in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects

Is it possible to import an application in ArcMap with .dll .tlb extension?
[image]

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: I used ArcObjects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

1. Open the arcmap
2. On menus Customize>Customize Mode
3. On Customize winow press 'Add From File' button
4. Browse to the dll and select the dll/tlb and press ok

If the dll is valid it will show a list of tools in the dll.
That's it. Done.